# SharpDX: Initializing a Texture2D from a DataStream fails (though Texture1D works fine)

Tags: c#, directx, textures, directx-11, sharpdx

I'm trying to create a SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D from in-memory data but always get a SharpDXException (HRESULT: 0x80070057, "The parameter is incorrect."). I have used a Texture1D for this purpose before which can be created without a problem.

I have reduced the code to this sample which still produces the exception:

```cs
using (var device = new Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug)) {
    // empty stream sufficient for example
    var stream = new DataStream(16 * 4, true, true);

    var description1D = new Texture1DDescription() {
        Width = 16,
        ArraySize = 1,
        Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
        MipLevels = 1,
    };
    using (var texture1D = new Texture1D(device, description1D, new[] { new DataBox(stream.DataPointer) })) {
        // no exception on Texture1D
    }

    var description2D = new Texture2DDescription() {
        Width = 8,
        Height = 2,
        ArraySize = 1,
        MipLevels = 1,
        Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    };
    using (var texture2D = new Texture2D(device, description2D, new[] { new DataBox(stream.DataPointer) })) {
        // HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [Unknown], ApiCode: [Unknown/Unknown], Message: The parameter is incorrect.
    }
}
```

Creating the texture without passing the data works fine. Can someone tell me how to fix the Texture2D initialization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the row stride of a texture 2D into the DataBox. Something like:

```
new DataBox(stream.DataPointer, 8 * 4)
```

Or in a more generic manner:

```
new DataBox(stream.DataPointer, description2D.Width
            * (int)FormatHelper.SizeOfInBytes(description2D.Format))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now :) Actually there is no corresponding constructor, only `new DataBox(datapointer, rowPitch, slicePitch)`. I assume slicePitch is for texture arrays and should be set to the size of the texture?

Comment: The third parameter is used for Texture3D (It means the size in bytes of a Z-slice) and should be set to 0 for Texture2D. Texture1D doesn't care about these parameters as the whole information is already stored in the Texture1DDescription (it is just using width * sizeof(pixelFormat)). This is explained in MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I think I have got it all (including the difference between DataRectangle and DataBox). Thank you for your support and for SharpDX!